# jQuery .load is not utilizing a saved $_SESSION/$_POST Variable

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create an "auto" refreshing dashboard page using some jquery and php.

Currently I have a "home" page that lists a range of devices which when clicked on open a new page with a $_POST Variable being the device ID.

On the new page I have a $_SESSION Variable being set to the $_POST variable mentioned above, which is then used to gather data from a database. This all loads and works fine on first load:

```
$_SESSION['d_id'] = $_POST['d_id'];
```

The issue comes in where I have set a jquery script as follows:

```
setInterval(reload, 10000);
            function reload() {
                $("#deviceData").load(" #deviceData > *");
```

This reloads a div containing the device data from the selected device ID, however when it reloads, the data is blank.

If I "hardcode" the $_SESSION variable to the device ID, then the reload function works as expected, so I am assuming it is losing the $_POST variable when it is reloading the div.

```
$_SESSION['d_id'] = '1234';
```

Would I be able to "re-post" the variable everytime it reloads the div, and if so, how?

Comment: `load()` sends a GET request, not a POST.

Comment: So how would I Post to the load()?
The load() is only reloading a div within the page, not the whole page itself. Am I able to add the $_POST variable in to the load() function?

Comment: No. `load()` can only ever make a GET request. If you need to send a POST you will have to build the request manually and use `$.ajax()` or `$.post()`, then pull out the relevant elements from the response, as it will return the entire HTML of the page. As a result of this, I'd strongly suggest you change how this page works. Firstly AJAX polling isn't a good solution as it does not scale, research web sockets for a better method. In addition, you should look to return JSON from the server which you then style in the UI as required. This saves bandwidth, and is a better separation of concerns.

Comment: So I can't add a variable to the paramaters of load()?
Perhaps one of:
```$("#myDiv").load("myScript.php?var=x&var2=y&var3=z")

$("#myDiv").load("myScript.php", {var1:x, var2:y, var3:z})```

Comment: You can do that, but again, it's sent as a GET request, not a POST.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around some more. Thanks for the websockets tip as well